# save character and occurance in an array of type struct{ch,int} of an input string

Tags: c

`name` is the input string.

`chars` is an array of this structre

```
struct {
    char ch;
    int occurs;
};
```

I want to count the times a certain character occurs and save both character and the occur value in the chars array.

Also the `ch` part of all the array chars is set to `'\0'` and the `int` part to `0`.

****I want the structure of the code to remain the same just where can the fix be done and how?

example: `yoyo` is the string input and I want for every character to be saved in the `chars` array like that (`y2 o2`).

```
for(j=0;j<strlen(name);j++){
    for(i=0;i<strlen(name);i++){
        if(chars[i].ch=='\0'){
            chars[i].ch=name[i];
            chars[i].occurs=1;
            break;
        }
        else if(chars[j].ch==name[i]){
            chars[i].occurs++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you looping twice for every character in name? I don't see the point. Also how did you create and initialized `chars`? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: i said its an array type struct read the description...is it any diffrent if i say Char char[50]?Char is struct {char,int}

Comment: maybe description too long.my bad

Comment: I advise you to rewrite your question, add correct punctuation marks, split it in paragraphs, add spaces after punctuation marks, your question is just hard to read. What is the meaning of `chars[i]`, what I mean, if you have 50 `chars`, what do `chars[0]`, `chars[1]`, etc. represent?

Comment: chars[0] is the first element of the array chars with is type struct Char .which struct contains{char ch int occurs} in it

Comment: That's not what I meant. Which characters does `chars[0]` store? `'a'`, `'A'`, the first character in `name`? I don't understand your loop. To be honest I don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: i want to count how many times a character in a string occurs.i want to get a result in which the character goes in the char part of an element of the array (ch) and the times it occured in the occurs

Comment: struct is like that{char ch     int occurs}and each element of chars is type struct(this struct)

Comment: You have two indexes (`i` and `j`) and two arrays (`chars` and `name`). You need to decide which index goes with which array. Also, the conditional expression in the `for` loop needs to match the array.

Comment: There isn't a simple fix. The inner loop `for(i=0;i<strlen(name);i++)` should be controlled by the current usage of the `struct` array (which you don't show), and `chars[i].ch=name[i];` should be `chars[i].ch=name[j];` the whole thing is very unclear.

Comment: @WeatherVane can u be more specific i didnt understand the first statement.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question many times, I think I understand your problem and
what you want to do.

The problem I see with you solution is that the inner loop is not correct. You
cannot just run `strlen(name)` times, it's too inefficient as this is the upper
bound, but you only need to check for all distinct values read so far. This number is on average smaller than `strlen(name)`.
Also you should first check the read character is already in `chars` and add it to it only if it
hasn't been found. What you should do is rather something like this:

```
// pseudo code
for all characters in name:
    found = False
    for all distinct cached values:
        if character is in cached value:
            found = true
            counter++
    if found == False:
        a new distinct value has been found
        add a new cache entry
```

So the code could look like this:

```
Chars chars[50];

size_t len = strlen(name);
size_t dv = 0; // number of distinct values

// initializing to 0
memset(chars, 0, sizeof chars);

for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
    int found = 0;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < dv; ++j)
    {
        if(chars[j].ch == name[i])
        {
            found = 1;
            chars[j].occurs++;
            break; // break inner loop
        }
    }

    if(found == 1)
        continue;

    // checking array bounds
    if(dv == (sizeof chars / sizeof chars[0]) - 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Too many distinct values, not enough space\n");
        return ERROR_VALUE;
    }

    // a new distinct value has been found
    chars[dv].ch = name[i];
    chars[dv].occurs = 1;
    dv++;
}

printf("The string '%s' has these distinct values:\n", name);
for(size_t i = 0; i < dv; ++i)
{
    printf("%c: %d times\n", chars[i].ch, chars[i].occurs);
}
```

But like I said, this is not very efficient, the worst case is in `O(n²)`.

A better approach would be to declare `chars` to be an array of dimension 256 of
`int` values, a `chars[i]` represent the `i`-th character in the [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) code:

```
int chars[256];

size_t len = strlen(name);

// initializing to 0
memset(chars, 0, sizeof chars);

for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    chars[(int) name[i]]++;

printf("The string '%s' has these distinct values:\n", name);
for(size_t i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
{
    if(chars[i] > 0)
        printf("%c: %d times\n", (char) i, chars[i]);
}
```

Comment: im trying to convert the first block of code into something that can run into mine.but i dont want to change the 2 loops or they way it looks.ive seen it run and it has structure same as mine.i just dont know what should i add.do i indent something diffrently?

Comment: and im pretty sure it didnt have an conditions between the for lops